# Do Hindu scriptures mention researchers or scientists?

Tags: science, research

Most of the Hinduism scriptures are from self experience of truth by Rishis.

Is there any mention about researchers or scientists in  scriptures? I mean are there any examples of persons from scriptures who are in research or does scriptures mention anywhere about research profession?

Note that the research I am talking about is the research happening in current days i.e., with proofs or experimental evidences other than self experiences of truth.

Comment: can you give an example of a research/claim made by a rishi that was NOT verifiable with experimental evidence?

Comment: @ram existence of divine beings and lokas..

Comment: Why do you say it is not verifiable ? They have clearly given methods by which you can see them for yourself ? Did you try those methods ?

Comment: @ram that is what I'm saying.. It can be gained by self-experience... Not by current research methods...

Comment: what is the difference between self-experience and current-research methods? I don't see a single difference between the two.

Comment: @ram by self-experience I can see other planets, but can't record it in a video to show to the world..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94433/discussion-between-ram-and-hanugm).

Comment: @hanugm this is illusion created by fake world we live today. Check asura gunas in Puranas and check how we go about today's world. No difference

Comment: "Note that the research I am talking about is the research happening in current days" This is off-topic question.

Comment: This looks topic as mentioned by Pandya!

Comment: @Pandya so, there is no concept of logical proof in scriptures?

Comment: @hanugm you can take astronomy texts like surya siddhanta etc... they accurately did motion of planets... eclipse calculation and so on. ..